# Linear Algebra Orthogonal Distance Question

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the question:

> Let $V$ be a vector space with an orthogonal basis $\{\mathbf{u}_1,\mathbf{u}_2,\mathbf{u}_3,\mathbf{u}_4\}$, $W=\mathrm{span}\{\mathbf{u}_1,\mathbf{u}_3\}$ and $\mathbf{v}=-\mathbf{u}_1+3\mathbf{u}_2+\mathbf{u}_3-2\mathbf{u}_4$.  Given $||\mathbf{u}_1||=2$, $||\mathbf{u}_2||=3$, $||\mathbf{u}_3||=2$, $||\mathbf{u}_4||=5$, determine the distance from $\mathbf{v}$ to $W$.

I do not know how to start the question. I know that the distance from $v$ to $W$ is the shortest distance and is the projection of $v$. I know I have to add the projections of $\mathbf{u}_1$ and $\mathbf{u}_3$ together. Can someone help me get started?

Comment: anyone? please help.

Comment: What do you mean distance between a vector and a subspace?

Answer (score 1):

We could find the distance from $\mathbf{v}$ to $W$ as the length of the vector $\mathbf{v}-\mathrm{proj}_{W}(\mathbf{v})$.  There's a short cut to finding this vector, however, using the following two points:

- We know that $-\mathbf{u}_1+\mathbf{u}_3 \in W$ (since $\{\mathbf{u}_1,\mathbf{u}_3\}$ is a basis for $W$), and $$\mathbf{v}=\underbrace{-\mathbf{u}_1+\mathbf{u}_3}_{\in W}+3\mathbf{u}_2-2\mathbf{u}_4.$$
- We know that $\mathbf{u}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{u}_4$ are mutually orthogonal.